# how to run both tests scalatest and junit?

Tags: scala, maven, junit

I have a project, there are some Scala tests for Scala code, as well as junit tests for Java. How to run Scala and Junit tests with Maven.
Project is multi-modular, with scala and java modules.

Comment: Where did you put the scala tests?

Comment: sorry, i did mistake in title of the question.

Answer (score 0):

You may have to manually specify the Java tests a work-around would be something like this

```
       <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.12</version>
            <configuration>
                <includes>
                    <include>**/*Suite.class</include>
                    <include>**/*Tests.class</include>
                    <include>**/*Spec.class</include>
                    <include>**/*Specs.class</include>
                </includes>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```